# React Native using conditional rendering still trying to access state even though set to false

Tags: react-native, api, conditional-rendering

I am trying to render a component but only after I get a response from the server.
for some reason it looks like react still trying to mount the component even though the condition is still false.

I tried to add some pre-checking before accessing the array but still the error persists. See code below:

MyComponent.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps'; // remove PROVIDER_GOOGLE import if not using Google Maps
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { getCarpoolByCode } from '../../services/CarpoolRidesService';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SimpleSpinner from '../global/SimpleSpinner';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = '...';

const Map = ({
    route,carpoolCode,token
}) => {

    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([])
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false)
    const [path, setPath] = useState([])
    const [source, setSource] = useState([])
    const [dest, setDest] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoader(true)
        console.log(token)
        console.log(route.params?.carpoolCode)
        getCarpoolByCode(token, route.params?.carpoolCode)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("MapPPPPPPPPPP")
                console.log(res)
                setSource(res.source)
                setDest(res.destination)
                setPath(
                    [
                        res.source,
                        ...res.path,
                        res.destination
                    ]
                )
                setLoader(false)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                setLoader(false)
            })
        // console.log(route.params)
        // setLoader(true)
        // setMarkers(route.params.results.map(it => it.carpoolData))
        // setLoader(false)
    },[])

    return (

        <>
                {
                    loader ? 
                    <SimpleSpinner/>
                    :
                    <View style={styles.container}>

                        {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(path)} style={{flex:1}}>
                            <Text>sadas</Text>

                        </TouchableOpacity> */}


                    <MapView
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
                    style={styles.map}
                    region={{
                        latitude:  path ? path[0][0] : 0,
                        longitude: path ? path[0][1] : 0,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
                    }}
                    showsUserLocation={true}
                    > 
                    <MapViewDirections
                        origin={source ? {latitude: source[0], longitude: source[0]} : {latitude: 32.162413, longitude: 34.844675}}
                        destination={dest ? {latitude: dest[0], longitude: dest[1]} : {latitude: 32.162413, longitude: 34.844675}}
                        apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
                    />
                         {path.map((marker, index) => 
                         {
            
                            console.log("marker")
                            console.log(marker)
            
                         return (
                            <Marker
                            key={index}
                            coordinate={{ latitude : marker[0] , longitude : marker[1] }}
                            // title={marker.title}
                            // description={marker.description}
                            />
                        )
                         }
                        )}

                   
                    </MapView>
                </View>
                }
        </>
       
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      token: state.users.user.login.token
    };
  }
  

  
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Map)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
      height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    map: {
      ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    },
   });
```

Error:

```
ypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in Map (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in CardSheet (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:619)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:612)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:494)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.js:26)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at JoinStack.js:18)
    in JoinStackScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at BottomTabView.tsx:55)
    in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:172)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:58)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:41)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:166)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at src/index.native.js:123)
    in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:146)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at BottomTabView.tsx:145)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:144)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:45)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at UserTabNavigator.js:29)
    in MainTabNavigator (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:58)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:41)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at DrawerView.tsx:183)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at src/index.native.js:123)
    in ScreenContainer (at DrawerView.tsx:162)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at Drawer.tsx:645)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at createAnimatedComponent.js:240)
    in AnimatedComponent(View) (at Drawer.tsx:638)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at createAnimatedComponent.js:240)
    in AnimatedComponent(View) (at Drawer.tsx:628)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Drawer.tsx:619)
    in DrawerView (at DrawerView.tsx:215)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at DrawerView.tsx:213)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.js:26)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at DrawerView.tsx:212)
    in DrawerView (at createDrawerNavigator.tsx:47)
    in DrawerNavigator (at DrawerNavigator.js:27)
    in MyDrawer (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in CardSheet (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:619)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:612)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:494)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.js:31)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at routes/index.js:29)
    in AppMainRouter (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction
    in MainNavigation (at App.js:31)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:26)
    in Provider (at App.js:25)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:47)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in Unknown (at AppContainer.js:134)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:40)
```

From the emulator it seems that the error is on line 72 (**latitude:  path ? path[0][0] : 0**) when I trying to access path.

if I remove the Map and put a button the prints the path variable, I get an array of arrays which should be accessible the way I did it.
Is there something wrong with how I constructed the component and the API call?

UPDATE:

I got this issue with source and dest too.
When I changed the source from an array to be 2 independent doubles (srcLat and srcLng) it appears to be working with no issues.

The only thing I can think of is that arrays are references to the content so it might make an issue, but still, the condition is set to false so it's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the initial state of the loader to true

```
const [loader, setLoader] = useState(true)
```

because `useEffect` is working as `componentDidMount` as the way you are using which means initially it will render the component and then call the `useEffect`.

useful link : [https://medium.com/@felippenardi/how-to-do-componentdidmount-with-react-hooks-553ba39d1571#:~:text=Functions%20passed%20to%20useEffect%20are,executing%20on%20the%20first%20rendering](https://medium.com/@felippenardi/how-to-do-componentdidmount-with-react-hooks-553ba39d1571#:%7E:text=Functions%20passed%20to%20useEffect%20are,executing%20on%20the%20first%20rendering).

Comment: Thank you it is working now :) I haven't thought about it till now, I guess I will have this bug in other places too.